# How to protect my server from false proxy requests

Tags: apache, proxy

I have a website, call it

```
http://www.example.com
```

Users create a site for themselves and they each get a sub-domain automatically, so something like

```
http://user1.example.com
http://user2.example.com
```

In addition, some users can use their own domain name, by creating a A-Record in their domain name DNS setup to point to my server's IP address.

```
http://www.myownname.com > 10.10.10.10 (my site's server IP address)
```

In my Apache VirtualHost, it's set up as follows

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias *
  UseCanonicalName Off

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/public/

  <Directory /home/public/>
    Require all granted
    Allowoverride ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Line `"ServerAlias *"` is there so that I can catch any domain name pointing to my IP address and then handle it via my site.

Everything is working well up to this point.

Now, recently, I've checked my Apache access log and I see strange access such as follows

```
10.10.10.10 - - [25/Jul/2014:12:48:04 -0700] "GET http://www.some-random-site.com/ HTTP/1.0" 200 1456
```

It looks like someone is trying to use my server as a proxy to access other sites. I've read quite a few pages in order to block this proxy requests (e.g. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse)

For example, if I use "default virtual host" to block everything except what's specified in my virtual host, all the custom domain names pointing to my server's IP address doesn't work anymore. But it does block the proxy requests.

How can I block proxy requests, while still being able to allow custom domain names via A-Record (or CNAME) pointing to my IP address?

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  Did you find a solution?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401312/log-shows-constant-get-requests-from-unknown-ips/